# Change stdout output in Ansible AWX/Tower

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

[image]

As it can be seen in the screenshot above, the Standard Out tab in the job output shows the standard output but XML-escaped, with garbled characters making output hard to read in jobs that run more complex tasks.

Is there any way to change this behavior and have AWX render the proper output?

For example, that above output should read:

```
Switched terraform to version "1.3.9"
```

PS: I am using AWX 17.0.1 on Ansible 2.9.17. Jobs, however, run on a custom environment with Ansible core 2.14.3 and python 3.11.2.